# How to calculate and visualize CQT in librosa with bins_per_octave other than 12?

Tags: signal-processing, librosa

On changing the bins_per_octave paramenter, the scale on y-axis changes and the plot shifts up if bins_per_octave is increased. How can I adjust the y-axis to see the full plot?

```
y, sr = librosa.load("CScale.wav") #sr = 22050
y_16k = librosa.resample(y,sr,16000)
print(y.shape) #(1422336,)
print(y_8k.shape) #(516041,)
C = np.abs(librosa.cqt(y, sr=sr,bins_per_octave=12))
C_16k = np.abs(librosa.cqt(y_16k, sr=16000,bins_per_octave=24))
print(C.shape) #(84, 2779)
print(C_16k.shape) #(84, 2016)

plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
librosa.display.specshow(librosa.amplitude_to_db(C, ref=np.max),sr=sr, x_axis='time', y_axis='cqt_note')

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
librosa.display.specshow(librosa.amplitude_to_db(C_16k, ref=np.max),sr=16000, bins_per_octave=24, x_axis='time', y_axis='cqt_note')

plt.colorbar(format='%+2.0f dB')
plt.title('Constant-Q power spectrum')
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

Here's my CQT [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyK3H.png).

How do I adjust y-axis of the second image so that it looks similar to the first image?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by adding n_bins and fmin parameters as mentioned in the [documentation](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.core.cqt.html), but I still don't understand how it works. I want to do it to include all 88 notes.

```
C_16k = np.abs(librosa.cqt(y_16k, sr=16000,fmin=librosa.note_to_hz('C2'), n_bins=60 * 2, bins_per_octave=12 * 2))
librosa.display.specshow(librosa.amplitude_to_db(C_16k, ref=np.max),fmin=librosa.note_to_hz('C2'),sr=16000, bins_per_octave=24, x_axis='time', y_axis='cqt_note')
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that `bins_per_octave` is also a parameter on `specshow`.